# Unexpected behaviour when calling `.values` on `bool[pyarrow]` typed `pandas.DataFrame`s

Tags: pandas, numpy, pyarrow

I have a situation where I have a bool-type dataframe, but some of them are constructed like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(True, index=[0], columns=[0], dtype='bool[pyarrow]')
```

and others are

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(True, index=[0], columns=[0], dtype='bool')
```

When I call `.values` I get different behaviour:

```
df1.values.dtype
> dtype('O')

df2.values.dtype
> dtype('bool')
```

I get similar behaviour for `dtype='float[pyarrow]'` vs `dtype='float'`. I just confirmed this is still true for pandas 2.1.4.

I am wondering if this is expected behaviour, or something that will eventually be fixed while pandas and pyarrow are getting more tightly integrated? It seems odd that on the one hand the work to construct the `numpy` array is done, but then the type is not filled in in what I would have considered a more consistent / efficient manner?

Comment: For context I was reading this: https://datapythonista.me/blog/pandas-20-and-the-arrow-revolution-part-i but I have a lot of use cases where I have dataframes of consistent types and do operations on axis=1, which can be slow in pandas but are much faster in numba using numpy arrays, so I drop down from pandas to numpy, which is how this difference came up

Comment: Pandas has extension dtypes that numpy does not.  For those the values dtype will be object (list like).  Expect the numpy array calculations to be slower, if they work at all.

Comment: Also look at `df.dtypes`

Comment: Which version of pyarrow do you have installed? I can't reproduce. But there is a known issue, when converting from arrow to numpy (which is basically what `df.values` does). Because numpy doesn't support null boolean, whereas arrow does, it upcast to `Object`. You can force it to use bool by calling `df1.to_numpy(dtype=bool)`. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22791

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `pyarrow` installed, but with another pandas extended dtype I get the same `object` behavior

```
In [521]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(True, index=[0], columns=[0], dtype=pd.BooleanDtype)

In [522]: df1
Out[522]: 
      0
0  True

In [523]: df1.dtypes
Out[523]: 
0    object
dtype: object

In [524]: df1.values
Out[524]: array([[True]], dtype=object)
```

If you want optimal `numpy` (or `numba)`) performance, stick with the 'plain' `bool`.